# SQL distinct keyword not filtering enough

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I`m new to sql and have been stuck on the following issue for almost a day now:

I have two tables that I pull values from, devices and devices_LOG. I need to display all the devices_LOG entries where devices.status = '1' AND I need them to be unique (ie I only want to see one devices_LOG entry for each device). My code looks like this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
                     devices_LOG.device_id, MAX(devices_LOG.LogDate) AS LogDate,
                     manufacturers.name, devices_LOG.LogType, devices_LOG.userName, 
                     devices_LOG.userFullname, devices.invnumber, devices.modelname,
                     devices.modelnumber
    FROM             devices_LOG 
    INNER JOIN
                     devices ON devices_LOG.device_id = devices.id AND 
                     devices_LOG.device_id = devices.id 
    INNER JOIN
                     manufacturers ON devices.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
    WHERE            (devices.devicestatus = '1') AND (devices_LOG.LogType = 'Out')
    GROUP BY         devices_LOG.device_id, manufacturers.name, devices_LOG.LogType,
                     devices_LOG.userName, devices_LOG.userFullname, devices.invnumber, 
                     devices.modelname, devices.modelnumber
    ORDER BY         devices_LOG.device_id
```

which is great for returning only entries for things that have device.status = '1', but it returns multiple log entries for something with the same device.id. So, the results of my query look like this

```
    device_id  LogDate       username    LogType    modelname   ...etc
    1          11/12/2011    foo         out        generic
    1          11/10/2011    world       out        generic
    2          9/10/2011     hello       out        generic3
    2          8/9/2011      bye         out        generic3
```

when I need it to look like this:

```
    device_id  LogDate       username    LogType    modelname   ...etc
    1          11/12/2011    foo         out        generic
    2          9/10/2011     hello       out        generic3
```

I tried using MAX on LogDate, tried grouping, select distinct, etc....but I just can`t figure it out. Any ideas?

I realize my sql statement is pretty ugly right now, probably because I have been trying everything I can think of up to this point with no luck, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: try adding a Having max(devices_log.logdate) to the end of the group by

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT works on rows, not columns, so it takes a view of all columns asked for and if *any* of those fields are different from the previous row, it is considered distinct. Ordering by LogDate DESC would get the latest dates to the top and grouping by device_id would keep similar devices together... but beyond that I'm stuck myself :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the log entry in a CTE and use ROW_NUMBER with partition to get the data you want.

For example if you wanted the oldest log entry, you could change the ORDER BY LogDate DESC into ASC.

```
WITH Log AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY LogDate DESC) AS RN, *
FROM Devices_LOG
WHERE LogType = 'Out'
)

SELECT DISTINCT 
                     Log.device_id, Log.LogDate AS LogDate,
                     manufacturers.name, Log.LogType, Log.userName, 
                     Log.userFullname, devices.invnumber, devices.modelname,
                     devices.modelnumber
    FROM             devices 
    INNER JOIN
                     Log ON Log.device_id = devices.id AND 
                     Log.RN = 1 
    INNER JOIN
                     manufacturers ON devices.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
    WHERE            (devices.devicestatus = '1')
    ORDER BY         devices.device_id
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I had no idea about CTEs. Can you recommend any good sql books that cover this sort of thing? Thanks again

Comment: I think most SQL Server related books cover Windowing functions and CTEs, including recursive CTEs. I haven't read any books that comes to mind that deals with these ".. ahem.. basic" topics ;) Talk to me when you want to get some book advices on sql server optimizer and internals, hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, but to get the max per device you should join with the log and find the max for each device, then no grouping should be required:

```
SELECT devices_LOG.device_id,
  devices_LOG.LogDate AS LogDate,
  manufacturers.name,
  devices_LOG.LogType,
  devices_LOG.userName,
  devices_LOG.userFullname,
  devices.invnumber,
  devices.modelname,
  devices.modelnumber
FROM devices_LOG
INNER JOIN devices
ON devices_LOG.device_id  = devices.id
AND devices_LOG.device_id = devices.id
INNER JOIN manufacturers
ON devices.manufacturer_id  = manufacturers.id
JOIN (SELECT devices_LOG.device_id,
  MAX(devices_LOG.LogDate) as LogDate
  FROM devices_LOG
  WHERE devices_LOG.LogType = 'Out'
  GROUP BY devices_LOG.device_id) maxLog 
ON maxLog.LogDate = devices_LOG.LogDate
WHERE (devices.devicestatus = '1')
AND (devices_LOG.LogType    = 'Out')
ORDER BY devices_LOG.device_id
```

Comment: This almost worked too but it still returned a few duplicate entries (duplicates as in having the same device id that is), although the results were much more clean than from the original query. The CTE and partitioning by row number that was suggested below worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this query which can be seen in action at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70c0e/6 :

```
;WITH Base AS
(
    SELECT
        D.id
        , MAX(L.LogDate) AS LastLogEntry
    FROM devices D
    INNER JOIN devices_LOG L
        ON L.device_id = D.id
    WHERE D.devicestatus = '1'
    GROUP BY D.id
)
SELECT 
    L.device_id
    , B.LastLogEntry AS LogDate
    , M.name
    , L.LogType
    , L.userName
    , L.userFullname
    , D.invnumber
    , D.modelname
    , D.modelnumber
FROM Base B
INNER JOIN devices D
    ON D.id = B.id
INNER JOIN manufacturers M
    ON M.id = D.manufacturer_id
INNER JOIN devices_LOG L
    ON L.device_id = B.id
    AND L.LogDate = B.LastLogEntry
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just group by devices_LOG.device_id ?

```
...
    GROUP BY         devices_LOG.device_id
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great place to use DENSE_RANK() and a CTE.

```
WITH LOG as 
    (
     SELECT devices_LOG.*,
           DENSE_RANK() over (partition by device_id order by device_id asc, LogDate desc) as nRank
     FROM devices_LOG
     WHERE nRank = 1
    )

SELECT DISTINCT 
                 LOG.device_id, LOG.LogDate AS LogDate,
                 manufacturers.name, LOG.LogType, LOG.userName, 
                 LOG.userFullname, devices.invnumber, devices.modelname,
                 devices.modelnumber
FROM             LOG   ---Notice I have changed which table you are selecting from. 
INNER JOIN
                 devices ON LOG.device_id = devices.id
INNER JOIN
                 manufacturers ON devices.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
WHERE            (devices.devicestatus = '1') AND (LOG.LogType = 'Out')
GROUP BY         LOG.device_id, manufacturers.name, LOG.LogType,
                 LOG.userName, LOG.userFullname, devices.invnumber, 
                 devices.modelname, devices.modelnumber
ORDER BY         LOG.device_id
```

Comment: if two entries has the same logdate, won't they get the same rank number, when using DENSE_RANK() ? If these log entries have the max date, it would show both of these, and not just one, as per requirements.

Comment: this looks similar to the other CTE-based solution (which worked),  but this gave me an error about nRank being an invalid column name

Answer (score 0):

Q#1: why are you repeating this line twice?
From devices_LOG 
INNER JOIN devices ON devices_LOG.device_id = devices.id 
                  AND 
                      devices_LOG.device_id = devices.id

Your issue is in manufacturers table. it has two values for name. 
manufacturers.name as username
Foo/World
Hello/Bye

That is why you are seeing two rows. it is not the device log/max issue.

Please correct me if I missed anything. (I followed your code order)

Comment: answer to Q1 -- my query analyzer actually auto added that; I didn`t have it originally. Also, even if I used different aliases for names it still gave me the same problem. The CTE solution worked though